# SQL View - Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I am trying to run a SQL View using code

```
select * from vwAdvancedSearch where [report Id] = 62 and r.RequestCompanyID = 2
```

but am getting an error returned

> The multi-part identifier "r.RequestCompanyID" could not be bound.

r.RequestCompanyID is not one of the fields in the select but does need to be a part of the criteria of the where clause.

How would I go about getting this where clause working.

thanks

Simon

Comment: please use `RequestCompanyID` instead of `r.RequestCompanyID` if this column in view `select * from vwAdvancedSearch where [report Id] = 62 and RequestCompanyID = 2`

Comment: You need to either alias your table, `vwAdvancedSearch ` with `r` or remove the `r` from `r.RequestCompanyID`, assuming there is `RequestCompanyID` column on `vwAdvancedSearch `.

Comment: as advised in the question, its not one of the columns \ fields I am selecting, but needs to be part of the where clause i am calling with

Comment: You can't do that directly. Use a derived table or cte.

Comment: Does `vwAdvancedSearch` have a `RequestCompanyID` column?  Or is it a column in one of its underlying tables?

Comment: @DStanley its in one of the underlying tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> r.RequestCompanyID is not one of the fields in the select but does need to be a part of the criteria of the where clause.

It doesn't have to be in the `SELECT` but *does* have to be in the table/view in the `FROM` caluse.  The problem is your query uses the alias `r` which you have not defined.  I suspect you want

```
select * from vwAdvancedSearch where [report Id] = 62 and RequestCompanyID = 2
```

or

```
select * from vwAdvancedSearch r where [report Id] = 62 and r.RequestCompanyID = 2
```

If `RequestCompanyID` is not in the view `vwAdvancedSearch` then you'll either have to use a different data source or join to a table that *does* have the column.

**EDIT**

> In my view I have `select * from table r where r.RequestCompanyID = @RequestCompanyID`. How do I pass the value to it?

When querying from a parameterized view, you pass the value of the parameter like you would pass it to a function:

```
select * from vwAdvancedSearch(2) where [report Id] = 62
```

Comment: so in my view say i have `select * from table r where r.RequestCompanyID = @RequestCompanyID` who to i pass the value to it?

Comment: the field is also in the table on the in the `from` clause too but there are about 6 joined tables on to it, hence the identifyer